# Cancel button in not operating correctly on open in menu in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6

I am downloading one file and trying to open the same in some existing application which supports it.

I am showing open in option action sheet by calling following method:

```
[documentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

It is showing open in menu correctly on all iOS versions but i have to tap on cancel menu several times in order to make it disappear.

If i change second parameter of methods from self.view to self.view.window then the button works fine for iOS < iOS6 but for iOS 6 it doesn't even show open in menu.

Is there any way that both button and open in menu should work?

I searched on internet n haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved problem by code like

```
if(ios6)
{
[documentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
}
else
{
[documentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view.window animated:YES];
}
```